# Delete is not working in case of UITableview

Tags: ios, swift

### MyTableviewController

```
var animalNameArray = ["cat","dog","lion"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    self.cancelButton.isEnabled = false

}



@IBAction func editButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.cancelButton.isEnabled = true

    self.tableview.isEditing = !self.tableview.isEditing
    sender.title = (self.tableview.isEditing) ?  "Done" : "Edit"

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        animalNameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete")!)
    return [remove]
}




//conditional Rearranging the table view cells

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

   }
```

I want to put the image (trash) instead of text, image is showing but the   delete action is not happening when trying to delete the row. I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I delete my tableview row? Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have any code in your remove action closure

Comment: yes i got it where i was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the cell at the indexPath that is passed in `editActionsForRowAt` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .left)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete")!)
    return [remove]
}
```

It will delete the row but it won't be consistent with the data inside the array. You can also delete item from the array at the specific index and then call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: `[IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)]`can be changed to `[indexPath]`

Comment: You need to remove the element from the data source array or you will get an exception

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete row from tableview you need to reload `rows`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .left)
           self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: .fade)
    }
    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete")!)
    return [remove]
}
```